# Как быстро проверить досягаемость сервера?

Tags: java

Такой вопрос, имеем InetAddress и номер порта. Возможно ли проверить, работает ли сервер быстрым способом, или без new Socket(...) не обойтись?

Comment: Для начала нужно дать определение фразы "работает сервер". Допустим, сокетом к нему подключиться можно. И что? Он может даже что то отвечать. Поэтому, нужно знать, что у сервера спросить и что он должен ответить. Если все совпало, тогда ок.

Comment: Вот мне и надо узнать, как проверить, что данный адрес прослушивается, и не более, без `Socket socket=new Socket(...`, т.к. взаимодействовать с ним я на первом этапе не собираюсь.
_______
Точнее не намереваюсь начать обмен данными.

Comment: @KoVadim, из вопроса вполне ясно, что именно хочет проверить автор.

Comment: @Etki не совсем ясно. Например, для udp, tcp случаев возможны разные решения: для udp вряд ли  что-то быстрее DatagramSocket можно сделать, а вот для tcp можно быстрее чем `new Socket`, например, ACK послать и посмотреть придёт ли RST (jni может понадобиться) в зависимости от того как автор определяет "досягаемость сервера". `InetAddress.isReachable()` (не рекомендую) тоже определяет "досягаемость сервера" в каком-то смысле (ICMP?). Если под "быстрым способом" понимается "ясный короткий код", то чтобы проверить доступен ли http сервер: `url.openConnection()` (`new HttpGet`) (совсем не быстро)

Comment: @jfs, ну, для UDP уж точно надо послать осмысленный запрос и прочесть ответ (а может и повторить запрос несколько раз, играясь с таймером, пока не  *поверите* в **недоступность сервиса** (сервер + приложение на указанном порту), а не во временные проблемы с сетью). 

ICMP может проверить только наличие ОС на сервере.

Для отсылки ACK  понадобится работать с RAW-сокетом, а значит иметь соответствующие права (обычно root) + та же игра с таймером.

--

Похоже, все это не может быть существенно быстрее/проще, чем просто начать работу. 

И вот тут-то возникает противоречие с пожеланиями автора...

Comment: @jfs, ему нужно проверить, открыт ли порт. Теперь поднимите руки, кто пришел сюда поумничать.

Comment: "Быстрым способом", быстрым с точки зрения производительности, без лишних запросов(если такое возможно) чтобы ответ (прослушивается порт или нет) пришел максимально быстро.  Используя TCP.

Comment: @avp: верно, в udp нет понятия открытого порта, поэтому необходимо запрос/ответ (которые может потеряться) выполнить (например, с помощью DatagramSocket, который я упомянул, просто его создавать без посылки запроса не имеет смысла). ICMP может быть отфильтрован, даже если сам сервер живой. Я упомянул jni (Java Native Interface) как раз для того, чтобы к raw-сокетам получить доступ (или java научилась сама это делать?).

Согласен, что если нет специальных нужд, то лучше использовать EAFP, а не LBYL подход в данном случае, то есть выполнять работу нормально и обрабатывать возникающие ошибки.

Comment: @jfs, OK. 

Не будем занудничать. 

Поскольку автор все же признался, что его интересует TCP, а в Java есть connect с таймаутом "из коробки", то IMHO  проще всего попытаться соединиться, а потом закрыть сокет  
(ничего отсылать-читать не надо).

--

Заранее согласен, что если серверное приложение логгирует все соединения, а по какой-то причине это для подобных проверок нежелательно, то ничего, кроме ACK (из jni, и со всей морокой с правами на клиенте), не придумать.

Comment: @avp: "ничего, кроме ACK", -- ещё существует [idle scan](http://nmap.org/book/idlescan.html), но я не думаю, что автору это надо. Во всём остальном: I think we are in violent agreement ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Быстрым способом", быстрым с точки зрения производительности, без лишних запросов (если такое возможно), чтобы ответ (прослушивается порт или нет) пришел максимально быстро. Используя TCP.

Как возможно более быстрая альтернатива к Socket.connect c timeout, можно выполнить tcp ping (послать неожидаемый ACK и получить RST в ответ), вот [пример кода (`ACKheartBeat()` функция)](http://insanelycrazy.net/development/faces/viewarticle.xhtml?id=23).

Как обычно, в вопросах улучшения производительности: необходимо измерить оба варианта.

---

avp комментирует:

> а ведь этот ACK/RST метод не позволяет узнать, готов ли порт принять соединение
>   (сервис работоспособен).
>   [The key to this type of heartbeat application is that the remote computer does not need to have any client application listening on the port to which the "ACK" packet is sent. The operating system will detect that the handshake did not occur properly and send a reset. The only requirement is the port cannot be blocked by a firewall.](http://insanelycrazy.net/development/faces/viewarticle.xhtml?id=23)
>   Или я ошибаюсь (что-то не до конца понимаю)?

@avp всё правильно, tcp ack ping говорит машина жива и порт не отфильтрован (если файервол не зловредный), то есть можно ли к данному порту подключится, но это не скажет о том ответит ли приложение (сервис работоспособен), которое может слушать на этом порту. [socket.connect](https://github.com/angryziber/ipscan/blob/b6e0b2c82a52298117e514d2f2196e26fa3ac418/src/net/azib/ipscan/fetchers/PortsFetcher.java#L105) тоже только говорит, что кто-то соединение принял, но там могут другие приложения находиться, например: [nginx или даже circusd могут быть живыми](http://circus.readthedocs.org/en/0.11.1/faq/#whycircussockets), но это ничего о web-worker не говорит.

Самый надёжный метод для проверки "досягаемости сервера" это выполнение реального запроса в тот момент когда его надо выполнить (EAFP: Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission), так как любые другие методы ведут к race condition: что-нибудь может сломаться между моментом проверки и моментом выполнения действительного запроса.

Comment: @jfs, а ведь этот ACK/RST метод не позволяет узнать, готов ли порт принять соединение.

    The key to this type of heartbeat application is that the remote computer does not need to have any client application listening on the port to which the "ACK" packet is sent. The operating system will detect that the handshake did not occur properly and send a reset. The only requirement is the port cannot be blocked by a firewall.

 

Или я ошибаюсь (что-то не до конца понимаю)?

Comment: @avp: я обновил ответ.