# ping серверов onion

Tags: python, сеть, tor

Можно ли как то пингануть web-сервер, который находиться в домене onion(то есть в сети tor) средствами python?

Comment: Скорее всего никак нельзя. TOR не гоняет UDP и ICMP-данные через себя.

Comment: это тот случай, когда вместо вопроса: "могу ли я выполнить запрос к сервису", следует просто "выполнить запрос". Связанный вопрос: [Как быстро проверить досягаемость сервера?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/373854/23044)