# ProxyChecker на Python

Tags: python, proxy

Собственно есть 2 вопроса:

1. Есть список бесплатных proxy серверов, как узнать "жив" ли сервер?
   (`requests` всегда возвращает 200 ответ сервера)
2. Каким образом можно через proxy скачать файл с целевого сервера? (один сервер отдает весь файл, другой 15-20Кб)

Comment: Избегайте задавать много вопросов в одном вопросе. Ваши вопросы можно вполне разделить на 2-а вопроса.

Comment: что такое "жив" зависит от задачи. В общем случае, просто реальный запрос в тот момент когда нужно выполните и обрабатывайте возникающие ошибки. [Как быстро проверить досягаемость сервера?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/373854/23044)

Comment: [Похожий вопрос в английской версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765305/proxy-check-in-python)